# Pressure over a surface

Tags: mathematical-physics, surfaces

Let $M$ be a regular surface and $F\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ a non-uniform force field on $M$. The pressure is defined as:
$$p=\frac{dF_A}{dA}\cdot \vec n$$
with $\vec n$ as normal vector of the surface.

What means by "derive the force respect to the total area $A$"?

Comment: I think (might be wrong) they want you to find the total amount of force over the area; I.e. Integrate the pressure over the surface to find the total force acting in M. Not sure what else you're given though.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I am not interpreting you right, but I think your question is "what does the expression $\frac{dF_A}{dA}$ mean?" Or "how do you differentiate Force with respect to Area?"

- "derive" = "calculate" or "figure out". It is *not* used for "find the derivative of".
- "differentiate" = "find the derivative of".

First, $A$ is area, but not the *total* area. Instead it refers to "unit area" - i.e., the area of an arbitrary region about the point of interest.

Second, $F_A$ is not $F$ itself, but is the total force applied across the arbitrary region.

So, for a given $p \in M$, 
$$\left.\frac{dF_A}{dA}\right|_p = \lim_{S \to p} \frac{\int_S F\,dA}{\int_S \,dA}$$
Where the limit is taken over regions $S$ containing $p$ and $S \to p$ means that the maximum distance from any point of $S$ to $p$ goes to $0$.