# Pressure Force in a fluid

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

The solution defined in [Pressure over a surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959199/439390) gives the basic definition of pressure on a surface.

In an incompressible, inviscid, steady flow, **plane flow**, the Force on any object may be due to pressure force and it is defined as shown.

$F_p = \dfrac{\rho}{2}\int_A V^2 d\vec{A} = \dfrac{\rho}{2}\int_A V^2 \hat{e_n} dA $

, where $\hat{e_n} $ is the normal vector of the elemental surface $dA$.
$ \vec{V}$ is the mean velocity of flow, $\rho $- the density

From where do we get the above expression for pressure force. 
The definition of normal force in  fluid is given by

$\sigma_{ii} = 2 \mu \dot{\epsilon_{ii}}  + (p - \dfrac{2}{3} \nabla . \vec{V})$(general case).  I think the pressure, $p$ is defined along with the normal stress components.

$\sigma_{ii}$ - the normal stress components
$\dot{\epsilon_{ii}}$ - the normal strain rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with **incompressible, inviscid** flow, the effects of viscosity are absent and the incompressibility condition $\nabla \cdot \mathbb{v} = 0$ applies.  Even in a moving fluid, the stress tensor is isotropic under these conditions with $\sigma_{ij} = - p \delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ii} = 1 $ and $\delta_{ij} = 0$ if $i \neq j.$  When the fluid is at rest, the static pressure $p$ is just the thermodynamic pressure.  When the fluid is moving, $p$ represents the average normal force acting on a fluid element.

The Euler equation for **steady** flow, expressing conservation of momentum, relates the fluid velocity to the pressure

$$\rho\mathbb{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{v} = -\nabla p.$$

Here I have ignored body forces which usually (eg., gravity) can be absorbed into the pressure.  From here we can derive the Bernoulli equation

$$p + \frac{\rho}{2}|\mathbb{v}|^2 = C$$

where $C$ is constant along a streamline (or constant everywhere in irrotational flow).  The surface of an object must coincide with a streamline since the fluid velocity normal to the surface is zero. In any case, the constant has no impact when integrated over a closed surface:

$$\int_A C\mathbb{n} \, dA = 0$$

This follows from the divergence theorem.  If $A$ encloses the region $V$, then for any constant vector $\mathbb{b}$ we have

$$\mathbb{b} \cdot \int_A \mathbb{n} \, dA = \int_A \mathbb{b} \cdot \mathbb{n} \, dA = \int_V \nabla \cdot \mathbb{b} \, dV = 0,$$

which implies

$$\int_A \mathbb{n} \, dA = 0.$$

Thus,

$$F_p = -\int_A p \mathbb{e}_n \, dA = \frac{\rho}{2}\int_A |\mathbb{v}|^2\mathbb{e}_n \, dA $$

Comment: In Euler equation, is $p$ the dynamic pressure? Thank you

Comment: @user1420303:  I had misused the term.  The [dynamic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pressure) is $\rho u^2 /2$ and $p$ is the called static pressure.  The sum is the total pressure which is the stagnation pressure when the fluid velocity is brought to $0$.

Comment: Thank you. So $p$ refers the to -1/3 Tr (stress tensor), and not to the thermodynamic pressure. Right?